# IOS Terminal App?

Tags: ios, terminal, ping

do you guys know of any apps that provide a real working Mac terminal from my iPad. I already have one for like host terminal and connecting but I would like one I could ping with you know stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

You won't have a "real" terminal on a non jailbroken device, although you can find some apps to realize a specific function such as Ping.

However if you have a jailbroken device you can install NewTerm (iOS 8 compatible) from this repo for instance https://cydia.hbang.ws/.